# Save innerHTML contents of TextArea to Google Drive file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm working on a page (https://www.jgloud.net) that will take contents typed into a HTML Textarea and save them to a file in Google Drive.  I've tried using RealTime as well as Google Drive REST but haven't been able to get it to work.

I've gotten the "[Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#getting_started)" button to work but that only allows uploading a file from the server to Google Drive, and I don't like the idea of saving their contents to my server, then uploading that file to Google Drive.

```
function renderSaveToDrive() 
{
  getFileName();
  var fname = filename;
  saveFileToDrive();
  gapi.savetodrive.render('savetodrive-div', 
                           {
                             src: fname,
                             filename: fname,
                             sitename: 'JGloud'
                           }
                         );
}

document.getElementById('render-link').addEventListener('click', renderSaveToDrive);
document.getElementById('savesourceButton').onclick = function() {document.getElementById('render-link').click();}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Going the realtime route involves a fair amount of setup, but there's an example of binding to a textarea [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_2_set_up_the_sample).

Comment: For a regular drive file, you either [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) or [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) the file directly from the client.

Comment: HeyHeyJC, I tried the [Realtime Binding](https://www.jgloud.net/realtimequickstart.html) you mentioned, but the results are not persistent over sessions.

Comment: Also, the examples you give are specific to binary data, not text.  The examples don't work with text data (Mimetype:text/x-java)

Comment: The examples I posted will need tweaking for your situation. But they ARE how files are uploaded to Drive, and how you bind using the realtime api, so whatever you're doing to tweak them is wrong. What are you trying, and what's happening?

Comment: And no, they work just fine with any data, any mime-type.

Comment: Also welcome to SO. Read the guidelines about asking good questions, you'll get better answers.

Comment: Thanks @HeyHeyJC.  I've tried to incorporate your suggestions with insert and update, and restated the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682784/save-text-from-textarea-to-google-drive-using-javascript).  I'm hoping I do it right.