# Save Text from Textarea to Google Drive using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload text typed into a Textarea to a Google Drive file (mimetype: text/x-java for java source code.)

I've tried to incorporate the update and insert methods mentioned in the [Drive Rest Files API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) but keep getting 401 errors.  The implementation can be found at https://jgloud.net.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  // save content to google drive
  function updateOrInsert(fileId, folderId, text, callback) 
  {
    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
    checkAuth();
    var contentType = "text/x-java";
    var myToken = accesstoken || gapi.auth.getToken();

    // if fileId exists, the file exists, use update method

    if (fileId) 
    {
      var metadata = {'mimeType': contentType,};

      var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
          text +
          close_delim;

      if (!callback) { callback = function(file) { console.log("Update Complete ",file) }; }

      gapi.client.request({ 
          'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/'+folderId+"?fileId="+fileId+"&uploadType=multipart",
          'method': 'PUT',
          'params': {'fileId': fileId, 'uploadType': 'multipart'},
          'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+myToken.access_token,
                       'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'},
          'body': multipartRequestBody,
      });
    }
    else
    {
      //no file present, must create a new one.  use insert method

      var reader = new FileReader(); 
      var fileData = new Blob([text], {type:'text/x-java'});
      reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
      reader.onload = function(e) {
      var contentType = fileData.type || 'text/x-java';
      var metadata = {
                       'title': filename,
                       'mimeType': contentType
                     };

      var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
      var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
          '\r\n' +
          base64Data +
          close_delim;

      var request = gapi.client.request(
          {
            'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
            'method': 'POST',
            'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
            'headers': {
                         'Authorization': 'Bearer '+myToken.access_token,
                         'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
                       },
            'body': multipartRequestBody
          }                             );
      if (!callback) 
      {
        callback = function(file) { console.log(file) };
      }
      request.execute(callback);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As Mr. Rebot implies, 401 errors (and, you'll find, several other errors too) mean your call isn't authorized. If you've set up an app and credentials in the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com), then the user has to [authorize](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication) that app to access their drive. If you're using gapi, then it stores and uses the authorization, but for straight http calls, you can also add the access_token as a query parameter: ?access_token=xyzblahblahblah. It's all a pain, but it's a one-time setup.

Answer (score 1):

try checking out and try the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) for javascript.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';

      var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];

      /**
       * Check if current user has authorized this application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          loadDriveApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
       *
       * @param {Event} event Button click event.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
          handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      /**
       * Load Drive API client library.
       */
      function loadDriveApi() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', listFiles);
      }

      /**
       * Print files.
       */
      function listFiles() {
        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'pageSize': 10,
            'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
          });

          request.execute(function(resp) {
            appendPre('Files:');
            var files = resp.files;
            if (files && files.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
              }
            } else {
              appendPre('No files found.');
            }
          });
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to Drive API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

This would be useful way to familiarize yourself to the code and some required steps when using Drive API. Hope it helps.

Comment: I put in a call to `authorize()`, which I had in my page.  So the source looks like: `...
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
    checkAuth();
    var contentType = "text/x-java";
    var myToken = gapi.auth.getToken();`

Comment: and later `...
       gapi.client.request({ 
          'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/'+folderId+"?fileId="+fileId+"&uploadType=multipart",
          'method': 'PUT',
          'params': {'fileId': fileId, 'uploadType': 'multipart'},
          'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+myToken.access_token,
                       'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'},
          'body': multipartRequestBody,
      });` but still a no-go.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined`.  I call on `checkAuth()`, then have `var myToken = accesstoken || gapi.auth.getToken();` to check if there is an existing accesstoken (from the global variable)  or I need to get a new token.  The error is when I add the header `'Authorization': 'Bearer '+myToken.access_token,` in the insert part of the method.  In either case the new changes aren't updated in the Google Drive file.

Comment: Setting aside your project, have you tried the javascript quickstart? That would definitely help you understand the flow of authentication in drive API. Kindly update your post for us to see what you have updated in your codes. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've updated the code above.  The quickstart what where [I started](https://www.jgloud.net/quickstart.html) but it doesn't reflect how to write to Google Drive.  The [insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) and [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) are what I tried to implement above, using the authorization from the quickstart (and the auth that works in my file read function.)

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the network tab for trying to save the doc to google, and it looks like it's returning an authentication error, have you looked through their client auth docs? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/auth/web-client#handling_authorization_requests

Here's the error,

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Comment: So, would adding `var myToken = gapi.auth.getToken();` and `'Authorization': 'Bearer '+myToken.access_token,` in the headers fix that (like what I did for the load method)?